# How to pass a function to a class that later modifies said class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a class that is modified by a function that is set upon construction.
The problem is, how do I get this function to modify the private fields of the class it's assigned to.
I have created a simplified code to explain:

https://jsfiddle.net/9zjc0k9e/ (same code as below):

The class to be modified:

```
foo = function(options) {
  let {func} = options; //The function we send on construction
  let a = []; //The variable we are trying to modify with the function

  function executer(v) {
    func(v);
  }

  return {executer};
};
```

Main:

```
//The function we will send when constructing:
let funk = function(v) {
   a.push(v); // <- this 'a' is the private member of the class we wanna modify
}

//Construct:
let bar = new foo({
  func: funk
});

//Run the function we sent through the public class function assigned to that
bar.executer(1); //<-- Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

The error I'm getting is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`. 
I hope I have cleared the problem enough, is there a way to get this done? Hack-ish is acceptable.

Comment: Looks like you need to read more about **closures**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir can you recommend and article / guide?

Comment: [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the outer function to see the local variable `a` without passing. The function tries to find the variables in that place where it is defined, means that the outer `funk` has no access any variable of `foo` implicitly. If `a` was an object variable you could access it via context binding.

You need to pass the reference of `a` too to the function.

```
let funk = function(v, array) {
   array.push(v); 
}
```

And call via

```
function executer(v) {
    func(v, a);
}
```

**Your Code**

```js
foo = function(options) {
  let {func} = options; 
  let a = []; 

  function executer(v) {
    func(v, a);
  }

  return {executer};
};


let funk = function(v, array){
   array.push(v);
}

let bar = new foo({
  func: funk
});

bar.executer(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have done something similar in the mean time, except that I'm passing 'this' reference to the function. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/0hpLgLuz/2/ - which solution do you think is safer?

Comment: Pass the variable into it. There is nothing about safe. If you `push` something into the array, so you change your array intentionally.